# THREE.AnimationClip always includes default pose keyframe during play()

Tags: animation, three.js, trim, clip

Skeletal animation issue (always plays default T-pose (keyframe 0) in (looped) animations using AnimationAction.play()).
Animations are imported from an .FBX file with a skeleton and animations using the FBXLoader.

I've trimmed the AnimationClip.tracks array() to remove the first keyframe(s), but it keeps including the base keyframe 0 T-pose during animations.

I tried emptying the AnimationClip.tracks array. If I then play() the associated AnimationAction, it still sets up some pose, suggesting the problem might not lie in the AnimationClip at all, but rather in parent Action/Mixer.

I've also tried offsetting the AnimationAction using "startAt(0.0333..)". But it still adds in the base pose during play().

```
//setup mixer for object
scene.mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( scene.obj );

// actions array (quick reference)
        scene.actions = [];
        for (i in scene.obj.animations) {
            scene.actions.push(scene.mixer.clipAction(scene.obj.animations[ i ] ));

// offset keyframe 0 (doesnt work since it still uses the keyframe 0 "T-pose" when the animation has finished playing and optionally loops)
scene.actions[i].startAt(0.0334);

// tried trimming with subClip fn, but again it'll throw in the T-pose.
subClip(scene.actions[3].getClip(), 0.03333333432674409 /* 30 fps: skip first frame @ 0.03333333432674408 */, 2);

// emptying the tracks array also doesnt work, since its still setting bones when I play/stop the AnimationAction.
scene.actions[3].getClip().tracks = [];
scene.actions[3].getClip().resetDuration();
}

function subClip(clip, start, end) {
    for (i in clip.tracks) {
      var track = clip.tracks[i];
        // (we depend on internal behaviour of trim() which uses Array.slice,
        // and doesn't modify the original array).
        clip.tracks[i].trim(start, end);

        // Once trim has been called, our track now has its own copies of
        // times/values, and no shared data. It's now safe to modify in-place,
        // which shift() does.
        clip.tracks[i].shift(-start);

    }
    // after modifying (key)frames, reset duration to new length
    clip.resetDuration();
}
```

I expect none of the keyframe 0 data to be used during animations. Especially on loop: they quite visibly stutter. (because of the jump in position + strange interpolation to the next pose).

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by exporting all animations into one large model file instead of a seperate file for every animation. Afterwards you can manually cut them up into seperate clips and it'll work just fine.